# Question for triangle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, inequality

In the proof of Cauchy-Goursat Theorem, the following fact was used:

> The distance between any point $z$ on a triangle and a point $z_0$ interior to the triangle is less than half the perimeter of the triangle.

I think it is true, but I don't know how to prove it. I'd like to prove the above assertion rigorously.

Please let me know if you have any comment for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: the distance between two points in a triangle (including its sides) is maximized when the two points are the vertices of the longest side. Then the problem reduces to the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the line through $z$ and $z_0$. It meets the triangle again at
$z_1$. Then $d(z,z_0)<d(z_1,z_0)$. But $z_0$ and $z_1$ divide the boundary
of the triangle into two paths from $z_0$ to $z_1$. One of these has length
$l$ which is at most half the perimeter. But by the triangle inequality,
$d(z_1,z_0)\le l$.